# Неправильный размер изображения

Tags: react-native

Делаю приложение в React Native. Слой неправильно отображается, будто увеличен и выходит за пределы экрана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проверьте расширение и тип экрана вашего эмулятора, вижу что проверяли, но одинаковые параметры системы и экрана, это не только это, возможно эмулятор имеет другой тип экрана, а это значит что на этой модели нужно делать отступы.
Под типом экрана я имею ввиду буквы после указания пикселей, в параметрах выбора эмулятора.

Answer (score 1):

Исправили ошибку? Может задать для `<Image resizeMode={тип}/>`?

вот ссылка на документацию по resizeMode: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#resizemode

Comment: Благодарю за ответ,  пока что нет возможности проверить - исправилось "само", при использовании сторонней библиотеки с примером, но возможно еще вернусь к этому.